# Using DCG remove non-numbers from a list

Tags: prolog, dcg

I need to write a predicate `CleanList/3` in Prolog by using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) which parses a list and returns a new list with the same numbers but all elements that are not a number removed.

For an example:

```
?- cleanList([1,2,d,67,3.2,'CSI2120',foo,5],LL).
LL = [1, 2, 67, 3.2, 5].
```

I wrote the base case and struggling to implement DCG with the recursive case. Can someone help me with this?

Base Case:

```
cleanList(L,LL) :- cleanList(LL,L,[]),!.
```

Comment: Your base case isn't a DCG, and is not a base case. A base case isn't recursive, but should give the basic, lowest level relation. The recursive call you have uses 3 arguments for a predicate that only takes 2.

Comment: You can use the fact that `number(X)` succeeds only if `X` is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by defining the base case like:

```
cleanlist([]) --> [].
```

which is pretty simple, all it does is returning empty list when the argument to `cleanlist/1` is empty list. 
You can also define the clause:

```
cleanlist([H|T]) --> (  {number(H)}  -> [H],  cleanlist(T) ;  cleanlist(T) ).
```

which keeps the head of the lists H iff it is a number and call recursively `cleanlist/1`.

Examples:

```
?- phrase( cleanlist([1]) ,L ).
L = [1].

?- phrase( cleanlist([1,3]) ,L ).
L = [1, 3].

?- phrase( cleanlist([1,2,a,c,3]) ,L ).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- phrase( cleanlist([1,2,a,c,3,m,k,l,o,"ABC",12]) ,L ).
L = [1, 2, 3, 12].

?- phrase( cleanlist([a,b]) ,L ).
L = [].

?- phrase( cleanlist([A,1,b]) ,L ).
L = [1].
```

Comment: Thank You! Is there any way to change this to work in a way that cleanListDCG/3 work correctly when called from cleanList/2 ?

Comment: Yes just rename the above to cleanlistDSG and add a new rule: cleanlist(L,L1):- phrase(cleanlistDCG(L),L1). which is the the asked cleanlist/2 predicate....